# Web service client/consumer - Browser or Webstart/JNLP or Swing

Tags: java, web-services, spring, security, soap

I have a webservice which does a number of things. A simple example of things it could do (note just example):

- Return list of products
- Update product price
- Add new product
- Update existing product
- Return product price
- Return product brochure + image
- Add product brochure + image

The first 5 services are simple enough in that a request is sent to the SOAP web service and it will either return a list or it will update an existing row in the database or create a new one.

The last two a slightly tricky in that they involve sending binary files to the service and recieving binary files from the service.

There is no problem in implementing the SOAP service on the server end. I already have a framework in place i now just need to implement the services. What i am having problems with is how to implement the client that will be consuming these services.

I have been reading up about SOAP clients and know that i can send the files as SOAP attachements but i dont quite understand how this is converted into a HTTP request.

Questions:

- I would like the client to be a web portal but i am not quite sure how you can call a web service from a web browser. is this possible?
- How does a web service call work from a browser? Is it a normal HTTP call?
- And most importantly, how would the upload/download of the binary files work?
- In terms of securing the requests, which is more secure? A web portal based client or a thick client based client?
- Is there any advantage in using Java Web Start/JNLP in place of a web portal or a thick client?
- Is it possible to mix and match between a web portal and Web start for the binary data transfer?
- Is it common practice to call a web service from a web portal (i.e. from a web browser)?

The other alternative i think is to implement the client as a thick client (Desktop application). The problem with this is that i have 0 experience in GUI Swing based applications.

One important aspect of the solution is that it has to be secure so whichever approach i use will need to be secured using certificates. The majority of the services will be implemented using Spring technologies. I am using Spring-WS for the Web service and will probably use Spring-MVC if it is doable as a web portal.

The Web Service and the Web Application will both be running in the same application server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I would like the client to be a web portal but i am not quite sure how you can call a web service from a web browser. is this possible?"

Well, if your ws supports HTTP (see below) you can theoretically send a request to the service from your browser, but how would it handle non primitive types returned by your service methods? Maybe you should have a look at RESTfull services too.

> "How does a web service call work from a browser? Is it a normal HTTP call?"

This depends on the webservice implementation you are using. Several webservices, i.e. Hessian & Burlap or Spring HttpInvoker, support http transport some might not. A call would be a normal http url having additional parameters and attachments (I guess the http's post method is the common way of accessing an http webservice).

> "And most importantly, how would the upload/download of the binary files work?"

This depends too. I lately tried uploading files using [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/#IntroductiontoHessian), but it failed when the file size reached a certain limit (about 30MB or so). A forum entry told me that this is caused by Hessians serialisation strategy, but I didn't find a solution. Check if your ws supports [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism), like [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) does, this made my upload working. There is an example for uploading images at the cxf homepage, too.

> "In terms of securing the requests, which is more secure? A web portal based client or a thick client based client?"

Both client types are sending/receiving data from a server so the connection has to be secured. Using a thick client (beside security tokens and trust policy) you may need a custom login function as well to authenticate your customer. So in the end its the right use of techniques that counts, as you know a standard http login can be very insecure too if its implemented badly.

> "Is there any advantage in using Java Web Start/JNLP in place of a web portal or a thick client?"

With WebStart you will need to build a custom client and at least a single page or servlet anyway. It is a technique for automated downloading/installing/upgrading your custom client.

> "Is it possible to mix and match between a web portal and Web start for the binary data transfer?"

Sure it is. If you are using Spring its very easy to let your clients access the very same functions. Just add your plain logic to a service facade (@Service). Then add browser support using the MVC controllers (@Controller) and ws support using a [ServiceExporter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html), for example.

> "Is it common practice to call a web service from a web portal (i.e. from a web browser)?"

Guess not, see REST services and above.

> "... The problem with this is that i have 0 experience in GUI Swing based applications. "

This might be a problem, but Swing applications can easily be build with NetBeans' graphical editor.

> "... whichever approach i use will need to be secured using certificates. The majority of the services will be implemented using Spring technologies."

For that have a look at [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html). This integrates well with a lot of your needs.

Hope I could help.

Comment: How does REST differ in the way the request is handled? (if the request comes from a browser)

Comment: Is it easier to use REST for the upload/download of binary files compared to SOAP?